# Minecraft Bukkit Plugin - Respond to Website

Tags: java, web, minecraft, bukkit

I was wondering if there was a way to make a plugin that has an event that's triggered when a user performs an action on my website. I would like to do this to make a custom store, since I don't like Enjin or Buycraft, since they are not very customizable.

Comment: You could try adding a RESTful service to your mod and see if it's active when you run the server.

Comment: I guess you could store data in a MySQL database when they do the action on the website, then make a `syncRepeatingTimer` that repeats every, say 1 minute (1200 ticks), that checks if the MySQL database contains anything, and does what the database tells it to do, then removes that row/column in the database when done

Answer (score 1):

You could have a php page that returns any tasks waiting to be done. Each task would have a unique id (maby mysql primary key?). Every 0.1-5 minutes (really any amount of time that is shortish) the plugin sends a http request to the page. The page would require either a get and/or post password to access, this prevents hackers/griefers/etc from gaining access to it. The plugin then does the tasks then sends another http request to another php file to mark the task as done (again with the password(s) for security), so it does not show up in future polls of new tasks (preventing it from being run again).